# Best practice for syncing passwords across multiple platforms?

Tags: encryption, passwords, synchronization

I'm designing a web-based app that will have its own authorization system (via Codeigniter-based Ion Auth) and will also be logging into a service in the background via API calls (Adobe Connect webinar services).  When the user creates their account on the base system, it will simultaneously create an account on the Adobe Connect system, using the user name and password they enter.  Easy enough to do.

The problem comes when making API calls to their account.  During initial sign-up, the Ion Auth code translates the user's password into a salted hash value but this won't work for the API calls, which require their in-the-clear password for authorization.  It wouldn't be an issue except that the user will also need to log into the Adobe Connect system directly for some functions.

My first thought is to create a field in the user's profile that stores their password in encrypted form, then decrypt it before passing to Adobe Connect.  Does anyone have a better method to suggest?

Thanks in advance,

Mark